# Where to store proprietary code and executable scripts?

Tags: security, python, users, executable, non-root-user

I have Python code that is run using a bash script. I want non-sudo users to be able to run it without making the Python code readable. What is the recommended pattern?

Two ways I considered:

1. Put all code under user's `HOME` and make it non-readable and executable as necessary
2. Put all code under `/usr/local` and add relevant bash scripts to `sudoers`
3. Put all code under `/root` and add relevant bash scripts to user's `PATH` or `bin` folder

As there are several ways to structure this, I'd love to hear what you think the *standard* or *recommended* way is.

Comment: Why do you need the code to be kept secret? That's generally not a good thing to do.

Comment: I'm ok with the bash script being readable but the Python codebase is proprietary and needs to be closed source

Comment: Why though? Did you hardcode passwords in it or something, or are you just worrying about the algorithm itself?

Comment: Yes, just the algorithm. Also, I'm asking just to understand what the best way to do this sort of thing is: clean way to let the user run my code and not be able to read it

Comment: I just got it to work the following way:

1. Put all code under users `HOME` folder

2. Remove read privileges

3. Put bash script that runs the code in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @tsotsi That can't be right. Scripts in /usr/local/bin aren't magically allowed to read things that the runner isn't allowed to read. Did you [setuid or setgid](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Permissions#Sticky.2C_setuid_and_setgid_bits)?

Comment: Yes, you're right, my mistake!

Comment: Running a Python script always means reading the script(actually , this applies to almost every modern program, including native ELF, language bytecode, text script). Users can hack Python's source code, let Python record everything it's reading to a file, compile it and then steal your algorithm. Unless your program is a pure static linked native code DIRECTLY(no PT_ITERP) executable by the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way to make sure users can't read the source code of something they are *causing to run* would be to **write a service which acts on the user's behalf** with the necessary privileges. Then give users a way to communicate with the server, such as a socket or a TCP port. At this point the code is no longer running in a context available to the user. Writing this isn't trivial, since you might need to consider for example users trying to use your service for privilege escalation.

Comment: Yes, that would work, thanks! One quick & dirty way to achieve similar functionality could be to let the user "schedule jobs" and then have a root background process or cron job actually run them?

Comment: Another partial solution is to [compile the Python script](https://www.wikihow.com/Compile-Python-Script)

Comment: If you want to suggest solutions to your own question you can post them as answers. That makes it easier for others to rate and comment on them.

Comment: Sure! The above two comments are partial solutions and I just submitted a separate answer with a trick that solves the problem by editing the sudoers file

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me is the following:

Add the following line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

As the user, run the script as follows:

```
sudo /path/to/script
```

That way the script itself (and all subsequent Python scripts) are run as root but at the same time none of them are readable or writeable

Comment: Running code as root opens up a whole other can of worms. I would not recommend this method.

Comment: 1. Make sure no code run by the script is writeable by the user 2. In the actual bash script use full paths `/usr/bin/python3` instead of `python3`. Would that be an exhaustive list of prerequisites to make this solution secure?

Comment: No. But this is getting very off topic.